# How to make a Solution explorer or project interface for my custom compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, interface

I am working on a 'Go' programming language compiler with visual studio 2012,c++,and bison tool.
I want to spice things up by making an interface, in witch I can start a new go project, write my packages and go code and organize it in a solution explorer as if this is the visual environment of my compiler.
I need to know how should I start with this, can that be done on visual studio or I need something like QT.
Please give me information about this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Visual Studio has a "Visual Studio" project style for MFC projects that starts with a UI fairly similar to VS's own (a "Solution explorer" on the left, "output" pane on the bottom, "Properties" on the right, all tabbed, pinnable, draggable, etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot I will check this out, but does MFC support bison tool ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use a Bison parser in an MFC project (i.e., I've done it, though not with the current version of VS and/or MFC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to [create your own project type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc512961.aspx) and to support external compilers; however, this is not straightforward. (I haven't done it myself; I just know that it is possible, since SDKs often add their own project types to Visual Studio.) Apparently, there is also a [Managed Package Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166157.aspx) that simplifies the process a little bit.